# Determine the condition on $n$ for $W_n$ to be critical graph.

Tags: graph-theory

The way my professor defines $W_n$ is the wheel graph of $n + 1$ vertices.  That is, the graph with $n$ vertices, each adjacent to the vertex of degree $n$, in the cycle.

We assume $W_n$ is a simple graph.

Here are my thoughts...

I know that
$$\chi (W_n) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}
3 & \text{if $n$ is even}\\
4 & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{array}
\right.$$

Assume $W_n$ is critical for any $n \geq 3$.  Given $\chi(W_n)$, we check if the degree of each vertex in $W_n$ is at least $\chi(W_n) - 1$.  We know that every $W_n$ contains the vertices of degree $3$ in the cycle of length $n$ and the vertex of largest degree $n$.  In order for $W_n$ to be critical, we need $3 \geq \chi(W_n) - 1$, which implies $\chi(W_n) \leq 4$.  Then, since the possible values of $\chi(W_n)$ are $3$ and $4$, we see that $W_n$ is critical for any $n \geq 3$.

I believe my approach is correct, but I may be wrong.

Comment: What is it that you want to prove ?  That $W_n$ is critical ?  If so, do not suppose it in the beginning.  And when you say "By the theorem", do you mean the we can color $W_n$ by 3 or 4 colors ?  And what do you mean by "in order for $W_n$ to hold" ?

Comment: Edited the details.  Hopefully, this might help.

Comment: You need to see if removing a vertex reduces the chromatic number.

Comment: Ah.  I see now.  So the "trick" of lemma I used doesn't really work.

Comment: Actually I think that wheels with $\chi(W_n) = 4$ are critical, but not those with $\chi(W_n) = 3$.  In the former case, remove the center vertex, and you get an odd cycle (3-colorable), or remove a cycle vertex - you get a path (2-colorable) plus the universal center vertex (3rd color).  But in the latter case, when $\chi(W_n) = 3$, remove a cycle vertex.  That will leave a triangle somewhere (just pick 2 other cycle vertices, plus the middle vertex), and your colorability is still 3.

Comment: @manuellafond I verified this via pictures and proofs.  Your intuition really works.